# NGX-Cookieconsent does not retrieve any cooking when clicking allow

Tags: angular

Im trying to get the Allow Cookies button to work with ngx-cookieconsent
but whenever i click on the allow, hasConsented() still returns false
and even after clicking on allow, when i refrsh the page the popup is always showing. SO far i have tried info, opt-in or opt-out with my settings and no sucess.

Buttons string text are on i18n file.

```
this.statusChangeSubscription = this.ccService.statusChange$.subscribe((event: NgcStatusChangeEvent) => {
      // you can use this.ccService.getConfig() to do stuff...
      if (event.status === 'deny') {
        this.openCookies()
      }

      if (event.status === 'allow') {
        this.popupCloseSubscription = this.ccService.popupClose$.subscribe(() => {
          this.ccService.toggleRevokeButton(false)
        })
      }
    })
```

```
const cookieConfig: NgcCookieConsentConfig = {
  cookie: {
    domain: environment.domain,
  },
  position: 'bottom-left',
  theme: 'classic',
  palette: {
    popup: {
      background: '#000000',
      text: '#ffffff',
      link: '#ffffff',
    },
    button: {
      background: '#f9ae05',
      text: '#000000',
      border: '#f9ae05',
    },
  },
  type: 'opt-out',
  content: {
    href: environment.privacyUrl,
  },
}
```

When i refresh the page, i have the message open again. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit late, but I have found an answer coming from the creator of ngx-cookieconsent:

https://github.com/tinesoft/ngx-cookieconsent/issues/4

updating the 'domain' property helped me on an angular app I've been working with in our project.

Comment: I had same problem. Changing domain to window.location.hostname helped me, Thanks a lot!